# Use Nutch with newest Elasticsearch

Tags: apache, solr, version, elasticsearch, nutch

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729940/outofmemoryerror-for-bin-nutch-elasticindex-cluser-all-nutch-2-1) I have managed to successfully integrate Nutch and Elasticsearch, albeit by downgrading my Elasticsearch version. How can I modify the Nutch source code to accommodate the latest version of Elasticsearch (0.90.2+)? I have tried modifying the Ivy dependency to this version of Elasticsearch and also modified Nutch's Elasticsearch compatibility code so it would build properly, but I end up with an error as Nutch times out waiting for a response from Elasticsearch; the two are unable to communicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the solution. You need to modify all references to the version number, both in `ivy/ivy.xml` and `pom.xml` (which is the file I forgot to change). Changing both `0.19.4`s to `0.90.2`s should do the trick. Also, you need to change `item.failed()` in `src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/elastic/ElasticWriter.java` to `item.isFailed()` to match the newer Elasticsearch refactoring.

Comment: FYI this question is referenced in a helpful blog post on the subject: http://www.sigpwned.com/content/nutch-2-and-elasticsearch

Comment: The version of nutch I am using (2.2.1) doesn't contain any `pom.xml` files, it's built using ant/ivy, so I only have the one place (`ivy/ivy.xml`) to update the elasticsearch version. I'm using elasticsearch-1.1.1, not quite got it working yet, but I'm working on it!

Comment: Haven't touched Elasticsearch in a while, good luck looking through those error logs!